# How can we define a "free energy" for a protein configuration?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, biophysics

In my naive understanding, a free energy (either Gibbs $G$ or Helmholtz free enrgy $F$) is a property defined for an ensemble of microstates under certrain circumstances. (NPT or NVT)

But I often see the word "free energy change" during protein folding process, how can we define the "free energy change" for a single structure under certain ensemble (suppose the folding process is done in one ensemble)?

My naive theory is that it is by considering the neighboring interactions that we can have two different "systems" after the folding process. Do not know whether it is the answer.

Comment: I think my initial guess is wrong...we often use collective variables to represent protein states, thus forming "macrostates of protein".

Answer (score 1):

As a macromolecule, a protein can adopt many configurations, and each configuration is characterized by an energy that depends on the local interactions. Therefore we have a canonical ensemble of configurations much like the ensemble of macroscopic systems on which we can define all the usual thermodynamic properties.

Comment: But here "each configuration" is like a "microstate" in an ensemble right? So my guess is that we call a "set of configurations" as a "macrostate" of protein, thus having the thermodynamic properties.

Comment: The “microstate” is a specific arrangement of the atoms of the protein. The collection of microstate is the “ensemble”. The “microstate” is “protein X at temperature T”.

Comment: It is exactly considering "protein X at temperature T" as the macrostate confuses me. Given this to be true, we can only assign "free energy" to the protein itself at a given temperature. When we consider the protein folding process at NPT ensemble, the Gibbs free energy of the protein can be calculated as a number.  But oftentimes we consider the "free energy change" in the folding process, I suspect that there is some way to assign "free energy" to "some configurations of the protein" rather than the "protein X at temperature T, pressure P", thus these configurations to be "macrostates".

Comment: The folded state is represented not a by single configuration but an ensemble of configurations, which we may think as fluctuations from the equilibrium position. Even in a crystal, where the positions of atoms are fixed, atoms move around their equilibrium positions.

Comment: I think that is the point! thanks